# ¿Como puedo declarar ese Heroe[]? ¿O que debo hacer para arreglarlo?

Tags: angular

No soy capaz de solucionar ese error, soy bastante nuevo, no se que hacer, el error es el siguiente: Function lacks ending return statement and return type does not include 'undefined'.ts(2366) ¿Como puedo solucionarlo?[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Puedes eliminar la imagen y poner el código fuente como texto? Mira [ask] y completa el [tour] de bienvenida para más información

Comment: Primero, no se debe insertar código en forma de imagen, es más práctico usar texto: conseguirás antes la respuesta a tu problema. Pon la pregunta completa: no indica el lenguaje usado, que pretendes...

Comment: Pon el `return heroeArr` afuera del for y problema resuelto.